# Meteors isServer ignored in windows

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Two weeks ago I started to learn courses on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/meteor-development/home/welcome) and there is an example where it shows how to use the `Meteor.isClient` method with `console.log` and Mongo. But it didn't work. My Windows CLI doesn't show anything in the output even after restart and if I try in the browser console type `console.log(Images.find().count())` it outputs 0.

```
Images = new Mongo.Collection("images");
if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.startUp(function(){
    if(Images.find().count() == 0){
      Images.insert({
        img_src:'1.jpg',
        img_alt:'Here i am !'
      });
    } //end of if have no images
  });
}
console.log('startup : ' + Images.find().count());
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your `console.log` is outside of your `Meteor.isServer` so it is pretty normal that it shows up in the client.

Second, if you want to show your log in the server, you have to either put it in the `startUp` function or in a method that you call in the client.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.isServer` works fine in windows, though for a long time now it has been [recommended](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure) that rather than use `Meteor.isServer` and `Meteor.isClient` you should split the code into `/client` and `/server` directories.

With new versions meteor, when you run `meteor create testApp` this following  is created:

[image: meteor directory structure]

All code in `/client` is only run on the the client, and all code in `/server` is only run on the server.

Creating/Editing these initial files to include the following log commands shows both where (client/server) and in which order the code is run:

`/client/main.js`

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
  },
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log('Ping! from /client/main.js - Meteor.startup()')
});

console.log('Ping! from /client/main.js - Top Level')
```

`/server/main.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log('Ping! from /server/main.js - Meteor.startup()')
});

console.log('Ping! from /server/main.js - Top Level')
```

`/shared.js`

```
// Runs on Both
console.log('Hi from /shared.js - Top Level')
Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log('Hi from /shared.js - Meteor.startup()')
});


// Runs on Server
if(Meteor.isClient){
  console.log('Hi from /shared.js - isClient')
  Meteor.startup(() => {
    console.log('Hi from /shared.js - isClient, Meteor.startup()')
  });
}

// Runs on Server
if(Meteor.isServer){
  console.log('Hi from /shared.js - isServer')
  Meteor.startup(() => {
    console.log('Hi from /shared.js - isServer, Meteor.startup()')
  });
}
```

`/lib/shared.js`

```
console.log('Ping! from /lib/shared.js - Top Level')

Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log('Ping! from /lib/shared.js - Meteor.startup()')
});
```

Here are the resulting logs from the server and browser:
[image]

On both the Client and Server, the `console.log` lines not in `Meteor.startup` blocks run first, followed by the `Meteor.startup` callbacks, because these are delayed until the server process has finished starting, or the DOM is ready.  They are executed in the same order in which the calls to `Meteor.startup` were made.

The calls not in a `Meteor.startup` block are executed as their files are loaded, following the [Default file load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order).